# How to dynamically call jquery function when browser width goes below 950px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to resize a video so that if fills 100% of its container ONLY when the browser width drops below 960 pixels. For reasons pertaining to inline styles I wrote this simple function in jquery. If works fine--but it is only called when the window is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 950) {
        $("video").width("100%");
    }
});
```

How would I write a similar jquery function which can change the width of the video dynamically as the browser window is resized? I have tried the following but to no avail.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if ( $(window).width() < 950) {
    $("video").width("100%");
}
});
```

**EDIT**Here is the new video html code:

```
<div id="sliderbg">
   <div class="container">
      <div id="slider" class="row">
      <div class="eight columns">   
    <div id="text-6" class="widget widget_text">            <div class="textwidget"><br>
<video id="wp_mep_1"   width="600" height="330" poster="http://www.first1444.com/wp-content/themes/lightningyellow/images/poster.png" controls="controls" preload="none"  >
    <source src="http://first1444.com/wp-content/themes/lightningyellow/videos/robotintro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />      
    <object width="600" height="330" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.first1444.com/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.first1444.com/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=http://first1444.com/wp-content/themes/lightningyellow/videos/robotintro.mp4" />          
    </object>       
</video>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#wp_mep_1').mediaelementplayer({
    m:1

    ,features: ['playpause','current','progress','volume','tracks']

});
});
</script>

<br/><h6 id="tagline">See <b><i>FIRST</i></b> Team #1444 in action building this years robot</h6>
</div>
</div><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if ( $(window).width() < 960) {
    $("video").width("100%");
}
});
</script>

</div><!-- eight columns -->
```

By the way I am using the foundation css framework. I doubt that would be causing the problem.

Comment: Could you use CSS and the min-width max-width values?

Comment: You just have a typo. See my answer below.

Comment: Please post the HTML containing the `<video>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo. It should be:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
```

resize() documentation: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: That's what Jakub said, and I have tried that before as said in the question.

Comment: Your example shows `$window` not `$(window)` as in my answer. The parentheses matter.

Comment: That makes sense. But I just fixed the error you pointed out and stuck in an alert() and it works fine. What doesn't work is the $("video").width("100%"); and I have no idea why.

Comment: Please show some HTML. There could be a million reasons why it's not resizing the `<video>` element.

Comment: I posted the link to the live site in the question. Here it is again:http://www.first1444.com/

Comment: Please post some HTML here. The live site won't help people looking at this question next year. Plus, I don't want to go digging through mounds of code to find the one tag you're having a problem with.

Comment: @Glen, it works. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4bKKK/12/. Plug in "100%" instead of the "300px" I've got there. Your video is being constrained by it's container. Please post the HTML surrounding (containing) the `<video>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use CSS Media Queries:

```
#my-element {
    width : 950px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 950px) {
    #my-element {
        width : 100%;
    }
}
```

This sets the element to `950px` wide unless the viewport is less than `950px` in which case the element is set to `100%` width.

Here is a demo using media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/G9gx6/

Here is a good source for finding what browsers support what: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

### Update

Of-course you can use JavaScript as well:

```
//bind to the windows resize event
$(window).on('resize', function () {

    //check if the viewport width is less than 950px
    if ($(this).width() < 950) {

        //if so then set some element's width to 100%
        $('#my-element').width('100%');
    } else {

        //otherwise set the element's width to 950px
        $('#my-element').width('950px');
    }

//trigger a resize event on the window object so this code runs on page-load
}).trigger('resize');
```

### Update

To optimize this code I would cache the `$('#my-element')` selection as well as throttle the `resize` event handler to only run once-in-a-while:

```
$(function () {
    var $element = $('#my-element'),
        resizeOK = true,
        timer    = setInterval(function () {
            resizeOK = true;
        }, 100);
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        if (resizeOK) {
            resizeOK = false;
            if ($(this).width() < 950) {
                $element.width('100%');
            } else {
                $element.width('950px');
            }
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G9gx6/1/

Comment: I understand this, but somehow the $element.width('100%'); is not working since the video doesn't change.

Comment: @Glen Here is a demo of the CSS Media Query solution working with the HTML5 video tag: http://jsfiddle.net/wqahT/

Comment: @Glen Here is a demo of the JavaScript solution working only with the `object` element: http://jsfiddle.net/wqahT/3/. Tested in Chrome 17 and Firefox 10.

Comment: Any reason for the down-vote? I'm always interested in how to improve my code.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is wrap your function in:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    alert('You resized the window!');
});
```

Reference: [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Yep, you're right, it must be my video resize that's messed up.